# Hibernate session closed after calling query.list()

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

In my service class, I have a method called `search()`. I create a session, call `createQuery()`, get the `list()` and at the end I am calling `session.flush()` but it throws an Exception saying that the session is already closed.

Other details:

- I am using Hibernate 4.0.6.RELEASE
- My context session is set to *thread*

**My code:**

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
// Build a StringBuilder that is built according to entered data

// Create the Query
Query query = session.createQuery(sql.toString());

// After this, do all the needed "query.setString(val1, val2)" stuff

// Now get the list (which does return values)
List list = query.list();

// Try to call flush on the session
session.flush(); // <---- This is where the exception is thrown (ServiceImpl.java 2716)
```

**The Exception:**

```
org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.errorIfClosed(AbstractSessionImpl.java:133)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.clear(SessionImpl.java:332)
at com.company.services.ServiceImpl.search(ServiceImpl.java:2716)
```

I looked to see if `list()` closes the session but it other examples I found do the `close()` after that call. My `close()` is in a finally-block where the above is in the try-block.

**My question is:**

Why is session closed when calling `flush()` if I have not closed it yet?

Comment: If you found it in other examples why didn't you do that?

Comment: @RomanC - I am. I just have the close in a `finally` block.

Comment: I don't see it in the question.

Comment: I added that sentence to my question for clarity

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Added the question. I am wondering why session is closed when I call `flush()` if I haven't called `close()` yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should not `flush` a session if you only do query a list. Second the session object might be managed by the hibernate or other frameworks that do close the session at the end of transaction that implicitly runs when you do the query. In most cases you don't need to close the session in the managed environment, and do it if you are using BMT. To fix the code you should check the session like

```
if (session.isOpen())  
  session.close();
```

Comment: So you're saying something else could have closed it after `list()`? I don't plan on keeping `flush()` there, it was just put there to try something. But when the exception was thrown, I thought it was odd and had to ask

Comment: yup, in your post you only said that your session is closed but, you don't know who did it.

Comment: Right. I just did some digging more and someone added a call to another method that also used the session and closed the session in there. So when it came back, it was closed. Thank you for the direction on that.